# Recieving error "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9420): colour" in R

Tags: r

```
editeddf$MajorAF <- 1 - editeddf$MAF

pdf(paste(var, "alleleFrequencyplot.pdf", sep = ""))

world <- map_data("world")
p <- ggplot(world, aes(long, lat)) +
  geom_map(map = world, aes(map_id = region), 
           fill = NA, color = "black") +
  coord_quickmap()

print(p + 
        geom_scatterpie(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = 1, r = 5),
                        data = editeddf, 
                        cols = c("MAF", "MajorAF"), 
                        color = c("lightskyblue1", "palevioletred2"), 
                        alpha = .8))
dev.off()
```

When running the above code in R, I get the following error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9420): colour
```

Not sure what the issue is, but when I remove the "geom_scatterpie" from the print statement, it prints a grey world map, which isn't exactly what I'm going for.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is it possible for you to share the dataset `editeddf`?  Double check the names of the of the variables in that dataset to confirm that they are called `long` and `lat` (capitalization matters in R).

Comment: Beneath your aesthetics error you mentioned that a grey map is not what you want. Would you explain what your map should look like?

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your color problem. Specify the colors for MAF and MajorAF seperatly in `scale_fill_manual` and not in `geom_scatterplot`. Then your pies will be colored blue and violet.

```
world <- map_data('world')
p <- ggplot(world, aes(long, lat)) + 
  geom_map(map=world, aes(map_id=region), fill=NA, color="black") + 
  coord_quickmap()
print(p + geom_scatterpie(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=1, r=5), data=editeddf, cols=c("MAF","MajorAF"), alpha=.8)+
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightskyblue1","palevioletred2")))
```